# Trying to convert coordinates for use in ArcGIS

Tags: convert, coordinates

I'm trying to input this data into ArcGIS and plot coordinates like this:

00⁰06.743   031⁰36.970 (coordinates south / coordinates east)

but I've failed so far and I was wondering if someone could tell me how to do this

I've tried to convert these coordinates with http://geoinfo.sdsu.edu/hightech/LM3/dd1.php or GPSvisualizer.com but they only allow you to convert 1 by 1 (I've got about 700 to convert, all saved into Excel spreadsheets)

So I'm hoping for a conversion tool where you can enter a complete spreadsheet at once and get it converted

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Would you be able to **edit** your question to clarify whether you mean ArcGIS for Desktop or ArcGIS Online when you say ArcGIS, please?  Also, what do your spreadsheet rows look like e.g. do you include the degree symbols?

Comment: A small sample from your spreadsheet for us to download would help about 1000% here.

Comment: Also asked on [GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/124633). Stuart had a better answer then I did--was there something unclear about this directions?

Answer (score 1):

In your spreadsheet, you should first convert your coordinates into decimal degrees

```
degree + minutes / 60 (+ second/3600, but you don't have seconds)
```

from the text string(assuming excel recognize your dot as a decimal separator), it would be

```
=LEFT(A1;SEARCH("°";A1)-1)+ RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-SEARCH("°";A1))/60
```

Because you are South and East, you also need to change the sign (negative values needed)

Then you can add your spreadsheet in ArcMap, [create an XY event](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhelp.arcgis.com%2Fen%2Farcgisdesktop%2F10.0%2Fhelp%2F0017%2F00170000006z000000.htm&ei=ol4BVZTjENfnauzsgbAP&usg=AFQjCNHc9Hx4SO1CODSxkOADhlZpu7_uCw&sig2=nxRdrCg5dAYyHwYjoL0LhQ&bvm=bv.87920726,d.d2s) and it will be projected on the fly in the coordinate system of the dataframe. (just check if you need to specify the transformation in case your datum are different).

Finally, if you need the coordinates, you can use the calculate geometry tool.